# Show a post list on homepage in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to develop a theme in wordpress. I am a newbie at this. What I want is to show a post list on the index.php page. I've created some post in database. The database name is "wordpress" and table name is "Posts". Database table has five column - Id, Title, Description, Author, Published_date. This is what I wrote in "index.php" -

```html
<div class="post">
 <?php $args = array("posts_per_page" => 5, "order_by" => "Id");
 $posts_array = get_posts($args);
 foreach ($posts_array as $post) {
  echo "<h3>" . $post->Title . "</h3>";
  echo "<p>" . $post->Description . "</p>";
  echo "<h5>" . $post->Author . "</h5>";
  echo "<p>" . $post->Published_date . "</p>";
  echo "</br>";
 }
   ?>
</div>
```

But this is not showing anything. Please help me with this.

Comment: is that all code you write to get data from db ? and are you using custom table or using the built-in post wordpress table ?

Comment: yes, it is all code for getting data from db. I am using built-in post.

Comment: what do you have as result ? error , or empty ?

Comment: just empty. there is a gap seems like there are something but nothing is showing.

Comment: use orderby instead of order_by

Comment: nothing happened

Comment: what if you try without , **"orderBy" => "Id"** ?

Comment: I've tried that too. same result

Comment: I've found the problem. The problem is about my theme. If I set the default theme the posts are showing, but it is not showing in my theme. What's wrong with my theme ?